# Why is there low hepcidin levels in hemochromatosis?

Tags: hematology

If hemochromatosis is iron overload and there is excess iron in the blood, why does the liver reduce hepcidin secretion (which increases the iron uptake) furthering the worsening of hemochromatosis?

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember it all depends on which type of hemochromatosis we are talking about. There are several types depending on the cause and some of those like the hemojuvelin gene mutation-related have low levels of hepcidin as the CAUSE of the hemochromatosis (since like you mentioned, seeing it as a consequence wouldn't make much sense)
The first 4 pages of this paper should clear things up a little bit https://www.aasld.org/sites/default/files/guideline_documents/Hemochromatosis2011.pdf